# Not able to see clearcase in Visual studio 2010

Tags: clearcase

I have recently configured ClearCase for the project, however I am not able to link it to ClearCase plugin. 
Also I am not able to view ClearCase in the tools->Options->SourceControl section of visual studio.

I have also checked on internet but it seems setup of Rational ClearCase 7 (v 7.0) itself comes up with Visual Studio addin. And there is no separate addin for it.

I have tried re-installing and re-configuring couple of times, Please guide me integrating Visual Studio addin.

Comment: If the setup package already includes the Visual Studio addin, why don't you install it? Just because there is one setup package doesn't mean that everything will be installed. Select only the components you want

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Visual Studio 2010 integration with ClearCase and CCRC](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21421687)":

> There is no Visual Studio 2010 integration available during an installation of ClearCase or CCRC versions 7.0.1.x or 7.1.1 or 7.1.1.1

You would need to use a [third-party utility like the one presented here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=984&uid=swg24024532).

> Note: With ClearCase version 7.1.1.2 and later, the steps below and integration utility are no longer necessary as support for Visual Studio 2010 is available through ClearCase and CCRC installs.